# Stop EF From Loading Entities When Assigning Association

Tags: entity-framework

Using Entity framework v4, and the POCO entity generator T4 templates.

The problem I have is that the Fixup methods are loading hundreds of entities when I assign an associated entity (see line 4 below).

```
Dim context = New SomeEntities
Dim list = context.Lists.FirstOrDefault(Function(l) l.ListId = 2)
Dim queryDetail = context.CreateObject(Of QueryDetail)()
queryDetail.CriteriaColumnType = context.CriteriaColumnTypes.FirstOrDefault(Function(cct) cct.CriteriaColumnTypeId = 145)
```

The `CriteriaColumnType` entity that is being assigned has a collection of `QueryDetail` objects, and when the assignment is made, the FixUp method on the `CriteriaColumnType` entity is lazy loading all of the associated `QueryDetails`.

How can I create the FK association and attach the `CriteriaColumnType` entity to my `QueryDetail` entity without loading all of the `CriteriaColumnType's` `QueryDetail` records?

Comment: To clarify, you have a `QueryDetail` with a property called `CriteriaColumnType` which contains a collection of other `QueryDetail`s.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need lazy loading here? You can turn it off:

```
context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = false
```

Comment: I actually considered using that, but it feels like a hack. Seems hard to believe that the casual Enitity Framework user would really want the associated entitiy's entire collection to be loaded in this case!

Comment: I don't think it's hacky. The context is a unit of work. Not all UOWs need lazy loading. It doesn't have to affect other UOWs, which might need lazy loading.

Comment: I agree with Steve. If the only way to avoid this behaior is to turn off the lazy loading, It should be considered as a bug. The only reason for this problem is change tracking (FixUp navigation properties on both sides of association). The code assigns value to navigation property on the one side. It in turn wants to assign the value to navigation collection on the other side but because of accessing the collection it initiates lazy loading.

Comment: @Ladislav: Actually, I agree that it "feels" like a bug. I didn't mean to imply otherwise. But my general position is that lazy loading is really easy to misuse (as this example demonstrates!), so it should be turned off except when you explicitly need it.

Comment: No pun intended, but turning off lazy loading unless required is... lazy. That's a bit backwards. You should only eagerly load the entire object graph is you need the whole object graph.

Comment: Further, if he's complaining about the lazy load happening, there must be a performance hit or something of that nature which would make eager loading equally undesirable.

Comment: @Andy, I'm *not* suggesting eager loading as an alternative. Many times (notably, *this* time) you don't need any loading at all. When you do, projection is often a better choice than eager or lazy loading. In short, it's good to be in full control of what you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem too. An operation that used to take milliseconds started taking 3-4 seconds to run, all because I added a navigation property pointing to a large table.

I solved the problem by just deleting all the fixup code from the T4 template - our project doesn't need that functionality anyway. I deleted everything from this line:

```
region.Begin("Association Fixup");
```

to the next region.End() call. I also deleted all calls to the fixup methods from the property setters, registration of CollectionChanged handlers, and the _settingFK flag.

See this question for more on why the fixup code is there: [Why is "Fixup" needed for Persistence Ignorant POCO's in EF 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945278/why-is-fixup-needed-for-persistence-ignorant-pocos-in-ef-4). It's trying to make sure that if you change one end of a bidirectional association, the other end is also updated. So, e.g., if you create a new BlogPost and set its User property to a user, the fixup logic will automatically add the post to the user's Posts collection.

marc_s answered the other question by linking to [POCO Template Code Generation Options](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/03/10/poco-template-code-generation-options.aspx). Removing the fixup code from the T4 template changes the template from #2 (basic POCO with fixup) to #1 (basic POCO without fixup).