# The type or namespace name 'FixupCollection' could not be found

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, poco, efpocoadapter

I generated POCO's using the EF POCO template. When I build my project, it tells me that I am missing a reference to the FixupCollection. Which library reference am I missing?

Here's the error:
*The type or namespace name 'FixupCollection' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*

Comment: Are you using ADO.NET POCO Entity Generator?If yes, go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2945278/why-is-fixup-needed-for-persistence-ignorant-pocos-in-ef-4

Comment: it should have generated a class called "<edmxFileName>.edmx" in the same location as the T4 generated classes.  If not, id try deleting and running the template again.

Comment: You're right, naillNoigeallach. I had resolved this yesterday itself but was too busy. I am posting an answer to my own question in case anyone else has the same problem. I searched and there aren't many links providing help to this problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I re-ran the template tool to re-generate the model classes and the problem went away.

I saw that the problem occurred because (I don't know how) I had accidentally deleted the code that defines the `FixupCollection<T>` class that gets generated by the template tool. This code is generated and shows up in the `YourModelName.cs` file under `YourModelName.tt` in the Solutions Explorer.

I am answering my own question because I was held up for a few hours on this and I Googled but couldn't find a single link that provided help on this topic. There were only a handful of other links all asking this same question but no answer.

Comment: It was commented out for me as well. I guess it's an issue with the EF tt generator.